# Copy Contents of File Into a New File

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that takes the contents of a text file, and copies it into a new file that the program creates itself.

This is the code I am testing at the moment:

```
from datetime import datetime

errorLogPath = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d_%H:%M') + ".log"

with open("Report.log") as logFile:
    with open(errorLogPath, 'w') as errorLog:
        for line in logFile:
            errorLog.write(line)
```

Currently the new file is created, but it is completely blank and has the wrong filename.  The filename should be `YYYYMMDD_HH:MM.log`  instead I am getting a filename which does not show the minutes and the file is empty.

EDIT: Removed an unnecessary `if` statement, but the code is still not functioning :\

Comment: replace `for line in logFile:` by `for line in logFile.readlines():`

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ why `readlines()` `logFile` is already an iterator over each of the lines in the file? OP: do the lines in the original file contain the string `"ROW"` - if not just remove the `if` condition.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `shutil.copy`…?

Comment: @deceze he would like to copy only a few lines from that file.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ Actually I am trying to copy the whole file :|  I suppose I am doing something quite wrong.

Comment: If you're trying to copy the whole file, what's the `if 'ROW' in line` for?

Comment: @deceze Bad copying from something I Googled to try to figure out how to do this apparently >__<

Comment: Well then, use `shutil.copy`, which defers the copy action to underlying OS/file system calls, which can potentially create an instant clone of the file without having to pipe it through memory in any way…

Comment: @deceze Thank you.  I will look up how to use `shutil.copy`

Comment: OP: Now you have edited your code - does it now work??

Comment: @AChampion No, it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to copy the file in python without using `shutil` module is:

```
with open("Report.log") as logFile, open(errorLogPath, 'w') as errorLog:
    errorlog.writelines(logFile)
```

To use the `shutil` module:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy("Report.log", errorLogPath)
```

Comment: using `shutil` the file is being created, but not correctly.  Instead of getting a file named `YYYYMMDD_HH:MM.log` I am getting a file named `YYYYMMDD_HH`.  Is my problem with the `errorLogPath` declaration?

Comment: @Skitzafreak remove the old file, I think you file is not created at all and you are checking an old file. AChampion code is a duplicate but fine.

Comment: What operating system are you on `:` maybe an illegal character for a file name.

Comment: @AChampion WIndows.  The `:` was my issue.  I changed it to a `-` and everything is copying over correctly.  Thank you for the clean way to do it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your path name, `:` is a reserved characters in windows, here is the [whole list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- - (asterisk)

the colon is referred as:

> A disk designator with a backslash, for example "C:\" or "d:\".

Therefore, the correct solution will be to change your `errorLogPath` to remove the `:` character.

Then, the best way to copy a file is yo use [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

```
from datetime import datetime
from shutil import copy

error_log_path = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d_%H_%M') + ".log"
log_file_path = "Report.log"
copy(log_file_path, error_log_path)
```

**Note**:

- You can open several files with a single `with` statement.
- It is better not to use [lower_case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) rather than camelCase for variable's name in python.

Comment: What's the deal with everyone wanting to read in the whole file into memory with `readlines()`, you don't need `content = logFile.readlines()` as `for line in logFile` in the comprehension would be sufficient and not unnecessarily read in the whole file into memory.

Comment: @AChampion true, but I don't get why OP's code is not working

Comment: Because the OP copied the code from google and has an unnecessary `if` statement.

Comment: @AChampion xD damn, ok

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I did edit the OP to remove that unnecessary if, but it still wasn't working regardless.

Comment: @Skitzafreak np, you should check the content of your file `Report.log` maybe

Answer (score 0):

try this, this has worked for me:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
errorLogPath = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d_%H:%M') + ".log"
ff = open(errorLogPath, 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(ff)
with open("Report.log","r") as logFile:
    reader = csv.reader(logFile)
    for line in reader:
        if "ROW" in line:
            csvwriter.writerow(line)
        else:
            continue

    ff.close()
```